# UIWebView fonts not found in iOS 8

Tags: ios, css, fonts, uiwebview, ios8

I'm updating my app for iOS 8 and have found UIWebView's do not display Helvetica Neue UltraLight correctly with both italics and bold applied, nor Helvetica Neue Light with the  tag.

Has anybody seen this or have any workaround?  I've reported this as  a bug to Apple, but they never do anything about bug filed.

For example:

```
em, i {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", 'Helvetica Neue UltraLight';
  font-weight:600;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am having about the same issue, css font setting isn't consistent with ios7 vs ios8.... 
It is annoying

Comment: I'm having an issue where ios8 doesn't apply the rule `font: -apple-system-body` if another `font-size` or `font` declaration occurs before it within the same css statement.  However, if you toggle either of the CSS properties off then on within the webkit console, it will then apply appropriately.  I wonder if this bug is related?

Comment: we feel your pain. Helvetica Neue variants got jacked up with iOS8. any workarounds?

Comment: and now in iOS 9, Helvetica Neue variants have AGAIN been messed up.